# CSS div's border unvisible

Tags: html, css

Dear more expert Pros!

What I'm unable to achieve - making the mcontent div stylized properly. Actually I have no idea why is not working this very simple css code. The lside and the content div are inside in the mcontent div. I'd like to have the mcontent div left and right border but I can't achieve that. If I take out the content and/or the lside formatting from the css file, the borders seemable. If I format the lside and the content div, the mcontent div even seems to me unvisible. (gave it background color and that is unvisible under these mentioned divs) I have no idea why. I've checked the html file for coding error - I did not discover any problem.

This is the HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="firstsite.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Website</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="navi">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 2_1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 2_2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 2_3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 3_1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 3_2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 3_3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 3_4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu 3_5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="mcontent">
            <div id="lside">
                <div id="lside_1">DIV 1
                </div>
                <div id="lside_2">DIV 2
                </div>
                <div id="lside_3">DIV 3
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div id="content">
                <h2 text-aling="center">1. menupoint - no submenu</h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis rutrum maximus leo, id euismod enim finibus ac. Fusce velit tortor, tincidunt a commodo et, elementum in enim. Ut eget varius elit, vel fermentum eros. Sed at nulla ornare odio rhoncus hendrerit sit amet nec massa. Integer at ultrices urna. Fusce a libero vel purus fringilla condimentum et sed eros. Fusce vestibulum velit eget libero bibendum maximus. Suspendisse in libero mattis magna fringilla interdum vel quis nulla. Pellentesque dapibus, elit eget efficitur pretium, diam dui luctus massa, non semper elit orci eget mi. Nunc condimentum pretium dapibus. Nulla iaculis urna nec eros commodo, eu lacinia eros ullamcorper. Phasellus euismod rutrum nulla id malesuada. In pellentesque turpis vel vehicula lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis rutrum maximus leo, id euismod enim finibus ac. Fusce velit tortor, tincidunt a commodo et, elementum in enim. Ut eget varius elit, vel fermentum eros. Sed at nulla ornare odio rhoncus hendrerit sit amet nec massa. Integer at ultrices urna. Fusce a libero vel purus fringilla condimentum et sed eros. Fusce vestibulum velit eget libero bibendum maximus. Suspendisse in libero mattis magna fringilla interdum vel quis nulla. Pellentesque dapibus, elit eget efficitur pretium, diam dui luctus massa, non semper elit orci eget mi. Nunc condimentum pretium dapibus. Nulla iaculis urna nec eros commodo, eu lacinia eros ullamcorper. Phasellus euismod rutrum nulla id malesuada. In pellentesque turpis vel vehicula lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis rutrum maximus leo, id euismod enim finibus ac. Fusce velit tortor, tincidunt a commodo et, elementum in enim. Ut eget varius elit, vel fermentum eros. Sed at nulla ornare odio rhoncus hendrerit sit amet nec massa. Integer at ultrices urna. Fusce a libero vel purus fringilla condimentum et sed eros. Fusce vestibulum velit eget libero bibendum maximus. Suspendisse in libero mattis magna fringilla interdum vel quis nulla. Pellentesque dapibus, elit eget efficitur pretium, diam dui luctus massa, non semper elit orci eget mi. Nunc condimentum pretium dapibus. Nulla iaculis urna nec eros commodo, eu lacinia eros ullamcorper. Phasellus euismod rutrum nulla id malesuada. In pellentesque turpis vel vehicula lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <h2>PHP Website by FGB 2016</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and this is the CSS file:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 940px;
  border: 1px solid red; /* just for seeing*/
}

#header {
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #808080;
  width: 900px;
  border: 1px #808080 solid; 
  border-bottom: 2px #FA801D solid;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}

#header h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#mcontent {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 892px;
  border-left: 5px solid #808080;
  border-right: 5px solid #808080;
}

#lside {
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;

}

#lside_1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#lside_2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#lside_3 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#content {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#content h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#content p {
  text-align: justify;
}  

#footer {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #808080;
  width: 900px;
  height: 60px;
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  border-top: 10px #FA801D solid;
}

#footer h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

/*
*   navi section
*/

.menu { 
  margin: 0px auto;
  height: 40px; 
  width: 900px; 
  background: #808080;
  padding: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #808080;
  border-right: 1px solid #808080;
  border-bottom: 10px #FA801D solid;
}

.menu li { 
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.menu li a { 
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 1.2em; 
  color: white;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}


.menu li:hover > a { 
  background-color: #FA801D;
}

.menu ul { 
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0; 
  top: 50px;
  background: #808080;  
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;  
}

.menu li:hover > ul { 
  opacity:1; 
}

.menu ul li { 
  height:0; 
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px grey solid;
  border-bottom: 1px grey solid;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li { 
  height: 40px; 
  overflow: visible; 
}

/*
* end of navi section
*/
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be careful when you post links. Because if the link to your Drive is reset, the post is irrevelant for someone else. So please edit you post and add the [tag:html] / [tag:css] code without [tag:php]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to style an empty div - no contents inside it but other div(s) - the style won't work until you add content or to give it a height

add min-height:200px; and display: table; to #mcontent to be like this

```
#mcontent {
 margin: 0px auto;
 width: 892px;
 border-left: 5px solid #808080;
 border-right: 5px solid #808080;
 min-height:200px;  
 display: table;
 }
```

here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/majali/vzx80x97/6/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunatelly this is not solve my problem, since the content div stuff's height can change depends on the content in it. The height: auto settings not working either. I've tried these before I wrote my question.

Comment: can you check it now I added min-height:200px;  and  display: table;

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="mcontent" >
            <div id="lside"> 
                <div id="lside_1">DIV 1
                </div>
                <div id="lside_2">DIV 2
                </div>
                <div id="lside_3">DIV 3
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div style="clear:both">
```

and style :

```
#mcontent {
  margin: 0px auto;
  display:inline-block;
  border-left: 5px solid #808080;
  border-right: 5px solid #808080;
}
```